# extending Element.prototype, issue with anchor

Tags: javascript, dom

Consider the following:

**JS**

```js
Element.prototype.text = function(str) {
  this.textContent = str;
  return this;
}

let div = document.createElement('div').text('div text'); //Works fine
let a = document.createElement('a').text('anchor text'); //Blows up
document.body.append(div, a);
```

The function I added to the prototype works fine On div or any other element I tried except the anchor element, and when I print the prototype chain for anchor element I do find the it has Element in it as expected.

Any idea why this does not work with the Anchor element in every browser i tried?

Comment: found the reason, it seems that Anchor prototype already has a method called text, changing the name of the method resolved the issue

Comment: [javascript - Why is extending the DOM/built-in object prototypes a bad idea? - Software Engineering Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/104320/why-is-extending-the-dom-built-in-object-prototypes-a-bad-idea)

Comment: @Delta In case you didn't know: Code-Snippets have an inbuild autoformat button: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwGHH.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement#Properties

> HTMLAnchorElement.text
>
> Is a DOMString being a synonym for the Node.textContent property.

So, `HTMLAnchorElement.prototype.text` is *shadowing* your custom `Element.prototype.text`.

Another problem is that `HTMLAnchorElement.prototype.text` is a *setter* - you cannot simply reassign it, eg

```
HTMLAnchorElement.prototype.text = function(str){
   this.textContent = str
   return this
}
```

because that will invoke the setter, resulting in `Illegal Invocation`. You'll have to delete the `text` property on the prototype first, and *then* assign to `HTMLAnchorElement.prototype`:

```js
Element.prototype.text = function(str){
   this.textContent = str
   return this
}
delete HTMLAnchorElement.prototype.text;
HTMLAnchorElement.prototype.text = function(str){
  this.textContent = str
  return this
}

let div = document.createElement('div').text('div text')
let a = document.createElement('a').text('anchor text')
document.body.append(div,a)
```

Comment: You don’t have to delete it first. You can easily change setters with `Object.defineProperty(HTMLAnchorElement.prototype, "text", { value: function text(){` … `} });`.

Answer (score -2):

This blows up because anchor tag doesn't have a text property/field, so it fails to set it. Create the element first, then create the text and attach it to the link.

```
var anchortext = document.createTextNode("your text here");
a.appendChild(anchortext);
```